# Tor won't work if I try to config custom ExitNodes

Tags: configuration, support

I want to  force Tor to use only the nodes of a specific country so I have edited the configuration file `torrc`in this way

```
ExitNodes wg1337, toxiroxiIT, CatRelay02, PhantomIT, torpidsITseflow2, CatRelay01, cristorIsblack, torpidsITseflow, torfatline, fatline, murdock311, KongbucksWelcome, Thorshammer, SingularityFTW, foghorn, Blackmesa, iristhaumantias, WooptThereItIs, Unnamed, midland, Unnamed, foghorn2, ziorufus, partyvan1, TestTurkey, carsol, clash, openspaceTorr01, manymanymore, ctrlCorf, packrat, MoreAssThanSoul, default, Unnamed, default, default, 000serverant1, TORNetworkRelayA01, Steppenwolfe, suca, default, r00t, FawkesSwissBlade, default, megabruco, stratmikefend, Unnamed, CirKu17, default, MadCat, lospartano, pisellonio, default, Meres
StrictExitNodes 1
# If non-zero, try to write to disk less frequently than we would otherwise.
AvoidDiskWrites 1
# Store working data, state, keys, and caches here.
DataDirectory .\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile .\Data\Tor\geoip
# Where to send logging messages.  Format is minSeverity[-maxSeverity]
# (stderr|stdout|syslog|file FILENAME).
Log notice stdout
# Bind to this address to listen to connections from SOCKS-speaking
# applications.
SocksListenAddress 127.0.0.1
SocksPort 9150
ControlPort 9151
```

where in `ExitNodes` line I have listed the names of nodes copied from *Tor Network Map*

Unfortunately editing the config file in this way Tor doesn't work and I cannot open any website.

Someone could help me?

Comment: The configuration option `StrictExitNodes` is deprecated; use `StrictNodes` instead.   
However, this should not stop your Tor client from functioning. In this case I would enable logging to a file and then see if it complains about anything.

Answer (score 2):

Tor decided not to support the naming system anymore. There is a proposal which proposes to [kill the Named flag](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/235-kill-named-flag.txt). Sebastian Hahn [announced](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2014-August/034380.html) this change in August 2014.

So instead of names you should use their fingerprints. For instance the relay *CatRelay02* has the [fingerprint CF6160C40FF2A9FB8A1CB5D02F4A2D56ACDC4CF6](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/CF6160C40FF2A9FB8A1CB5D02F4A2D56ACDC4CF6). Just insert this into you `torrc` and it should work again.